# How to Stop Double Clicking/Double Posting of form?

Tags: google-apps-script

Using UiApp to collect data from a form, but I have users double clicking the submit button. This runs doPost twice.  Granted, they have to click mighty fast to get it to actually post twice, but it happens.

My questions is: has anyone had experience in disabling the submit button, say with an onMouseUp?  Is there a better way to do this?  I've been told to be wary of adding multiple onClick handlers to buttons, as it can be unstable.  Any stable solutions to this?

I have to use a submit button as there is a file upload in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've faced this problem and ever since Google introduced ClientHandlers, there is a way out. 
Just add a client handler to your submit button disabling it (and remember to enable it when you are done with the server handler function or doPost)

```
var plswait = app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setEnabled(false).setText('Please wait...'); 
var btnSubmit = app.createSubmit().addMouseDownHandler(plswait);
```

is my favourite.

Comment: It appears as if the submitButton needs to run a full click cycle, up and down to call doPost.  Tried splitting the events with the to MouseDown (doPost), MouseUp(plswait), but then it seems doPost can't find the file upload. The handlers seem to be breaking the special relationship between doPost and SubmitButtons

Comment: I'm giving the answer a check, as I think it will solve the problem for many, but if anyone finds a way to get this to work with a true submitButton and file upload, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but to work around it I created a second "false" button that becomes visible when the submit button is clicked, at the same time the "real" submit button visibility is set to false. Here's the basic code:

```
var button = app.createSubmitButton('Submit').setId("button")
  .setEnabled(false)

var falseButton = app.createButton('Submit').setId("falseButton")
  .setEnabled(false)
  .setVisible(false);

var handler = app.createClientHandler()
    .forTargets(button).setVisible(false)
    .forTargets(falseButton).setVisible(true); 

button.addClickHandler(handler);

panel.add(app.createHorizontalPanel().add(button).add(falseButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer didn't work for me because the MouseDown handler didn't let the ServerHandler run. But it gave me the right direction. I just added the Client handler to disable the button before I added the Server Handler...and that seemed to work to prevent the double click. Like this:

```
  var submitButton = myapp.createButton("Submit");
  var myServerHandler = myapp.createServerClickHandler("myServerHandler");
  var pleaseWait = myapp.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setEnabled(false).setText('submitting...'); 
  submitButton.addClickHandler(pleaseWait);
  submitButton.addClickHandler(myServerHandler);
```